# ¿Como crear una paginacion en php ? sin database y variables de session

Tags: php, session, paginación

Quiero mostrar imagenes de 5 en 5 (como una cartelera de cine) pero no puedo realizar la paginacion.

```
<?php
 $archivos=scandir("sitio2"); //escanea directorio
 echo "<center>";
 echo "<table>";
 session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['contador'])){
 $contador=$_SESSION['contador'];
}
else {
$contador=2;

}

 $cuenta=0;

while($contador<=7){ //aqui tengo que mostrar de 5 en 5 , puse 7 para 
mostrar los primeros cinco
if($cuenta==0){
    echo "<tr>";
}

echo "<td>","<img src=sitio2/$archivos[$contador] width=140 height=193> 
 <br>", substr($archivos[$contador],0,-4),"</td>";
$cuenta++;
if($cuenta==5){
    echo "</tr>";
    $cuenta=0;
}
$contador++;
$_SESSION['contador']=$contador;
}

$max=$contador+5;
echo "</table>";
echo $_SESSION['contador'];
echo $contador;

echo "<a href=directorio2.php> Siguiente</a>";
echo "</center>";
```

Tengo problema para hacer que empiece desde una variable de inicio, y termine con una variable de final, quisiera saber como colocar esas variables.

Comment: Empezaria por leer un poco sobre arreglos (array) puedes crear un array apartir del conteo de los archivos en tu directorio, lee también sobre opendir de php. con eso ya tendrás las bases para recorrer el arreglo y mostrar la cantidad de archivos que quieras.

Comment: Lo más fácil para hacer una paginación con php es pasar la página mediante variables $_GET, así sabes en qué página estás

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre dos formas para realizar la paginacion:

```
<?php
$archivos = scandir("sitio2");
if (isset($_REQUEST['pos'])){
    $inicio=$_REQUEST['pos'];
}
else {
    $inicio=0;
}
if($inicio==0){
    $limite=5;
}
else{
    $limite=$_REQUEST['pos']+5;
}

$i=$inicio+2;
$cuenta=0;
$contador=2;
echo "<table>";
while($i<$limite+2 & $i<sizeof($archivos)){
    if($cuenta==0){
        echo "<tr>";
    }

    echo "<td>","<img src=sitio2/$archivos[$i] width=140 height=193> <br>", substr($archivos[$i],0,-4),"</td>";
    $cuenta++;
    if($cuenta==5){
        echo "</tr>";
        $cuenta=0;
    }
    $contador++;
    $i++;

}
echo "</table>";
if($inicio==0){
    echo "<font size=3> Anteriores </font>";
}
else {
    $anterior=$inicio-5;
    echo "<a href='paginacion2.php?pos=$anterior'><font size=3> Anteriores </font> </a>";
}
if($i+3 <sizeof($archivos)){
    $proximo=$inicio+5;
    echo "<a href='paginacion2.php?pos=$proximo'><font size=3> Siguientes </font> </a>";
}
else {
    echo "<font size=3> Siguientes </font>";
}
?>
```

Esta primer forma es mas corta pero si existe otro tipo de archivo que no sean imagenes las va a mostrar entonces la segunda forma es la siguiente:

```
<html> 
<title>Galeria</title> 
<head> 
<?php  

$arbol = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 

$dir_sub = ("/php/sitio2/"); // DIRECTORIO DE IMAGENES 

$i_carpeta = $arbol . $dir_sub ;  

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

 $path = $i_carpeta; 
 // Extracción de imágenes.  
 $dh = opendir($path);  
 $archivos = array(); 
 while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {  
        if($file != "." && $file != ".*") { // FORMATO ARCHIVOS A MOSTRAR 
                if(substr($file, -4) == '.jpg') $archivos[] = $file; 
        if(substr($file, -4) == '.png') $archivos[] = $file; 
        if(substr($file, -4) == '.gif') $archivos[] = $file; 
        if(substr($file, -5) == '.jpeg') $archivos[] = $file; 
        }  
 }  
 closedir($dh);  
 sort($archivos);  
//parte 1: 
 $total_imagenes=count($archivos); 
 $image_a_mostrar=5; 
 //estos valores los recibo por GET o request 
 if(isset($_GET['pag'])){ 
        $imagen_a_empezar=($_GET['pag']-1)*$image_a_mostrar; 
        $imagen_a_terminar=$imagen_a_empezar+$image_a_mostrar; 
        $pag_act=$_GET['pag']; 

 }else{ 
        $imagen_a_empezar=0; 
        $imagen_a_terminar=$imagen_a_empezar+$image_a_mostrar; 
        $pag_act=1; 
 } 
 //parte 2: determinar numero de paginas 
 $pag_ant=$pag_act-1; 
 $pag_sig=$pag_act+1; 
 $pag_ult=$total_imagenes/$image_a_mostrar; 
 $residuo=$total_imagenes%$image_a_mostrar; 
 if($residuo>0) $pag_ult=floor($pag_ult)+1;  
 //parte 3: navegacion 

?> 

</head><body> 
<div align="center">
<table border="1">
<?php
$cuenta=0;
?>


 <?php  
 while($imagen_a_empezar<$imagen_a_terminar){ 

        //si se pasa de total de imagenes salir de bucle 
        if($imagen_a_empezar>=$total_imagenes) break; 
        ?> 
<?php
if($cuenta==0){
       echo "<tr>";
   }
?>
<td>
<a href="<?php echo $dir_sub; ?><?php echo $archivos[$imagen_a_empezar]?>"> 
    <img src="<?php echo $dir_sub; ?><?php echo $archivos[$imagen_a_empezar]?>" width="200" height="300"/> <br> 
<?php echo substr($archivos[$imagen_a_empezar],0,-4);?>
</a> 
</td>
<?php
$cuenta++;
if($cuenta==6){
       echo "</tr>";
       $cuenta=0;
   }
?>

<?php $imagen_a_empezar++;} 
?> 
</table>
<?php 
echo "<br>";
 echo "<a href=\"?pag=1\" onclick=\"Pagina('1')\">Primero</a> "; 
 if($pag_act>1) echo "<a href=\"?pag=".$pag_ant."\" onclick=\"Pagina('$pag_ant')\">Anterior</a> "; 
 echo "<strong>Pagina ".$pag_act."/".$pag_ult ."</strong>"; 
 if($pag_act<$pag_ult) echo " <a href=\"?pag=".$pag_sig."\" onclick=\"Pagina('$pag_sig')\">Siguiente</a> "; 
 echo "<a href=\"?pag=". $pag_ult."\" onclick=\"Pagina('$pag_ult')\">Ultimo</a>"; 
 ?> 
</div>
</body></html>
```

Es mas larga pero defino que tipo de archivos puedo recibir, considero que es una mejor solución.